# config files with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, ini

I am diving down into the world of Python, practicing by writing a simple inventory based application for my dvd collection as a means to get aquainted to working with sqlite3.

As part of my project, I am using a ini file for settings, and then reading the values from that in a shared library that is called from another file. I am curious as to feedback on my methods, especially my use of the config file, and best coding practices around it.

The config is formatted as follows, named config.ini

```
[main]
appversion = 0.1.0
datasource = data\database.db
```

my utils library is then formatted as follows:

```
import os
import sqlite3
from configparser import ConfigParser


CONFIG_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config/config.ini')


def get_settings(config_path=CONFIG_PATH):
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read(config_path)
    return config


def db_connect():
    config = get_settings()
    con = sqlite3.connect(config.get('main', 'datasource'))
    return con
```

Finally, my test lookup, which does function is:

```
from utils import db_connect


def asset_lookup():
    con = db_connect()
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dvd")
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        print(row)
```

My biggest question is in regards to my building of the data connection from within utils.py. First I'm reading the file, then form within the same script, building the data connection from a setting within the ini file. This is then read by other files. This was my method of trying to be modular, but I was not sure if its proper.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Comment: Short answer, you shouldn't read `config.ini` more than once. `config` should be a global object. Normally, we have a split file named `config.py`, and we `from config import config` to use config object globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you could do something like this to cache your objects so you don't create/open them over and over again whenever you call one of the functions in utils.py:

```
import os
import sqlite3
from configparser import ConfigParser

CONFIG_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config/config.ini')
config = None
con = None

def get_settings(CONFIG_PATH):
    global config 
    if config is None:
        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read(CONFIG_PATH)
    return config


def db_connect():
    global con
    if con is None:
        config = get_settings()
        con = sqlite3.connect(config.get('main', 'datasource'))
    return con
```

While this might solve your problem, it relies heavily on global variables, which might cause problems elsewhere. Typically, that's where you switch to classes as containers for your code parts that belong together. For example:

```
import os
import sqlite3
from configparser import ConfigParser

class DVDApp:
    CONFIG_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config/config.ini')

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigParser()
        self.config.read(self.CONFIG_PATH)        
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(self.config.get('main', 'datasource'))        

    def asset_lookup(self):        
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dvd")
        results = cur.fetchall()
        for row in results:
            print(row)
```

Initializing config and connection objects held in `self` reduces to just 3 lines of code. Thereby making it almost unnecessary to split your code over several files. And even if so, it would be enough to share the one instance of `DVDApp` between modules, which then holds all the other shared objects.

Comment: your second solution is working perfectly, thank you! I am far from any sort of Python expert, so this is a good learning bit for me.